# Why reassigning arguments doesn't work with arguments that have default values?

Tags: javascript

I have a really weird question that I don't know how it occurs.

When I reassign an argument with `arguments[0] = 42`. The `arguments[0]` and the first argument `a` are both `42`. Which is expected.

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
  arguments[0] = 42;
  console.log(a, arguments[0]);
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

But when I tried with a function that has an argument with a default value, the first value `a` doesn't get reassigned anymore. Can someone explain this discrepancy?

```js
function foo(a, b, c = 3) {
  arguments[0] = 42;
  console.log(a, arguments[0]);
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: that is weird - personally, I'd never touch `arguments` like that to begin with :p

Comment: Never seen this before. Does this happen in browsers as well? Chrome / firefox / safari?

Comment: @TKoL Yeah I tried all these browsers and the outcomes are consistent.

Comment: [Rest, default, and destructured parameters | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#rest_default_and_destructured_parameters): _"Conversely, non-strict functions that are passed rest, **default**, or destructured parameters **will not sync new values assigned to `argument` variables in the function body with the arguments object**. Instead, the arguments object **in non-strict functions with complex parameters will always reflect the values passed to the function** when the function was called"_

Comment: @Andreas that looks like an _answer_.

Comment: @HaoWu I'm most surprised by that! All the browsers doing it consistently! It's a miracle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [note](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) in the spec about this - you only get a mapped `arguments` object when you're not using ES6+ syntax (or in strict mode) in your function declaration (emphasis mine):

> NOTE: A mapped argument object is only provided for non-strict
> functions that don't have a rest parameter, any **parameter default**
> value initializers, or any destructured parameters

As you are using a [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), your arguments object doesn't get mapped, just like it doesn't when you're in [strict-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

```js
function foo(a, b, c) {
  "use strict";
  arguments[0] = 42;
  console.log(a, arguments[0]);
}

foo(1, 2, 3); // 1 42
```

Answer (score 3):

[The arguments object - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) -> [Rest, default, and destructured parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#rest_default_and_destructured_parameters)

> In strict-mode code, the arguments object behaves the same whether or
> not a function is passed rest, default, or destructured parameters.
> That is, assigning new values to variables in the body of the function
> will not affect the arguments object. Nor will assigning new variables
> to the arguments object affect the value of variables.
>
> ...
>
> Non-strict functions that are passed only simple parameters (that is,
> not rest, default, or restructured parameters) will sync the value of
> variables new values in the body of the function with the arguments
> object, and vice versa.
>
> ...
>
> **Conversely, non-strict functions that are passed rest, default, or destructured parameters will not sync new values assigned to argument
> variables in the function body with the arguments object. Instead, the
> arguments object in non-strict functions with complex parameters will
> always reflect the values passed to the function when the function was
> called (this is the same behavior as exhibited by all strict-mode
> functions, regardless of the type of variables they are passed)**